# Magento Extension Page Layout

Tags: category, layout, cms-block

I've installed a news extension but I don't succed to customize layout. For all other pages, I've the category and inside I call the cms static block to uniform all the layout.. Now instead with this extension I've its page that seems to have the standard magento layuot with the pool on the right. Where can i modify this layout or how I can use the cms block ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that for each extension we have an xml layout folder of the theme. Inside it, there's the layout model with 1 or 2 or more column and then the reference where to insert all block needed. 
In my particular example:

```
<clnews_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>commercelab/clnews/news.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="clnews/news" name="news" template="clnews/list.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
```